# pytest wants to us incorrect python 3 version

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, pytest, python-venv

pytest is looking for python3.4 for some reason.

```
$pytest
-bash: /usr/local/bin/pytest: /usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.4: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I'm using OS X, I had python3.4 previously installed but have been using python3.5 for a while now. 
**edit**: I may have upgraded incorrectly, which could well be causing this issue.

I installed both 3.4 and 3.5 using `brew`.

```
$brew list python3
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/bin/2to3-3.5
...etc.
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/bin/python3.5
...etc.
```

I am using a virtual env with python3.5 and pip3. I have the following set:

```
$echo $VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON
/usr/local/bin/python3.5
$ echo $VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV
/usr/local/bin/virtualenv-3.5
```

Python3 and pip work fine:

```
$ which python
<blah>/.virtualenvs/<blah>/bin/python
$ python
Python 3.5.1 (default, Dec 26 2015, 18:08:53)
$ pip -V
pip 8.1.1 from /<blah>/.virtualenvs/<blah>/lib/python3.5/site-packages (python 3.5)
```

I have tried the `--isolated` flag with pip when installing pytest:

```
$ pip install -h
...
--isolated    Run pip in an isolated mode, ignoring environment variables and user configuration.
```

which went like this:

```
$ pip install --isolated pytest
Collecting pytest
  Using cached pytest-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): py>=1.4.29 in /<blah>/.virtualenvs/<blah>/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from pytest)
Installing collected packages: pytest
Successfully installed pytest-2.9.1
```

but pytest still looks for python3.4.

Something must be hanging around from python3.4, which pytest installation unfortunately is picking up on.

Can anyone shed some light on this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahem.

To run pytest you use:

```
$py.test
```

and not

```
$pytest
```

The `pytest` executable `/usr/local/bin/pytest` is from over a year old, I assume an old install.

```
ls -plah /usr/local/bin/pytest
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin   154B 15 Apr  2015 /usr/local/bin/pytest
```

I removed it and uninstalled and reinstalled pytest with pip. Reinstalling doesn't re-create `/usr/local/bin/pytest`. In hindsight, I'd be surprised if pip did put anything outside of the active `.virtualenv` directory.

In summary:

[image]

Comment: `pytest` is an executable installed by older versions of `pylint` (via `logilab-common`).

Comment: meh.  We all do the face palm from time to time.